# Is there an efficient way to soft sync a local dataset to a SQL Server table using Entity Framework Core, a generic method and composite keys?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to build a reusable soft sync (find deleted records but update them, not delete them) method. I'm using `EFCore.BulkExtensions` for the UPSERT, but retrieving the missing records is taking a ton of time. Since the method is generic, I do not know the keys ahead of time and am attempting to use reflection to get the key values and build a hash for comparison. The problem is, using reflection means I have to pull the full dataset into memory and filter based on that which is proving to take a very long time.

Below is what I currently have

```
public static async Task SoftSyncAsync<TContext, TEntity>(this TContext @this, IList<TEntity> entities, string deletedFlagName = null)
    where TEntity : class
    where TContext : DbContext
{
    // this method just creates a transaction and processes the bulk upsert (await context.BulkInsertOrUpdateAsync(entities, _config))
    await ProcessAsync(@this, entities, OperationType.Upsert);

    // this gets the property to update if the record is deleted
    var isDeletedProperty = deletedFlagName != null
            ? typeof(TEntity)
                ?.GetProperties()
                ?.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name.Equals(deletedFlagName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            : typeof(TEntity)
                ?.GetProperties()
                ?.FirstOrDefault(p => (p.PropertyType == typeof(bool) || p.PropertyType == typeof(bool?))
                    && (p.Name.Equals("Deleted", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                    || p.Name.Equals("IsDeleted", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                    || p.Name.Equals("IsDeletedFlag", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)));

    if (isDeletedProperty != null)
    {
        var entityType = @this?.Model?.FindEntityType(typeof(TEntity));

        // this gets the property in the key. Might be 1 but could be many
        var keyProperties = entityType
                ?.FindPrimaryKey()
                ?.Properties
                ?.Select(p => p.PropertyInfo)
                ?.ToList();

        // this creates a hash set for the entities know are in the table (Not deleted)
        var entityHashes = entities
            ?.Select(e => string.Join("_", keyProperties.Select(kp => kp.GetValue(e).ToString())).GetHashCode())
            ?.ToHashSet();

        // THIS IS THE SLOW PIECE. Creates the hashes for records in the table and compares against the set above
        var leftOverEntities = @this
                ?.Set<TEntity>()
                ?.AsNoTracking()
                ?.ToList()
                ?.Where(e => (bool)isDeletedProperty.GetValue(e) != true && !entityHashes.Contains(string.Join("_", keyProperties.Select(kp => kp.GetValue(e).ToString())).GetHashCode()))
                ?.ToList();

        // Updates the "deleted" records
        if (leftOverEntities?.Any() == true)
        {
            leftOverEntities?.ForEach(e => isDeletedProperty.SetValue(e, true));
            await ProcessAsync(@this, leftOverEntities, OperationType.Update);
        }
    }
}
```

I've read a few places about using expressions to perform reflection operations but I couldn't find how to do that with composite keys

Comment: I didn't get from the question what you are trying to do after `BulkInsertOrUpdateAsync` and why it is not enough just to call this function?

Comment: That will just insert and update what is in the entities dataset (which I get from an external set). After that happens, I need to find out which records in the table don't exist in the entities dataset and update an IsDeleted flag

Comment: Well, do you stick with BulkExtensions or want to try another extension which works with temporary tables and Merge operator - best solution your case?